# Selection rows in Pandas

Tags: pandas

how to select rows that are between 2 dates and I have 2 column valid from and valid too. I want to select rows between certain dates that match up these 2 columns.

Answer (score 0):

This will provide a view of rows where the `DateFrom` and `DateTo` columns are between the dates you specify. Is this what you wanted?

```
from datetime import datetime

df.loc[(df.DateFrom >= datetime(2018, 1, 1)) & (df.DateTo <= datetime(2018, 2, 1))]
```